# Get combinations of whole words in a string with rest of the words in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following string sentence as input

```
'test string of whole words'
```

And as output, I need an array of strings of different combination of words including rest of the words like this

```
test string of whole words
teststring of whole words
test stringof whole words
test string ofwhole words
test string of wholewords
teststringof whole words
test stringofwhole words
test string ofwholewords
teststringofwhole words
test stringofwholewords
teststringofwholewords
```

I have tried to write following code to achieve above output but it only works to remove one space at a time. Following code is just a trial from me.

```
function getSpaceIndices(str) {
  let spaceIndices = []
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === " ") {
      spaceIndices.push(i)
    }
  }
  return spaceIndices
}

let str = 'test string of whole words'
let strArray = str.split(" ");
let combinationArray = []

// let spaceRemoveCount = 1
let spaceIndices = getSpaceIndices(str)
let currentIndex = 0
while (currentIndex < spaceIndices.length) {
  let tempStr = str.slice(0, spaceIndices[currentIndex]) + str.slice(spaceIndices[currentIndex] + 1);
  combinationArray.push(tempStr);
  currentIndex++
}
console.log(combinationArray);
```

Comment: Please add more detail, what was an input, output, and your expected output? Where in the code do you think the issue is?

Comment: @t3dodson I updated the question to mention the input and output more clearly. Code I wrote is just a try I did. No need to edit/extend from it if its the wrong way. You can start from scratch. I just need the above output. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to do it fairly easiy with recursion, just for a start you can try as below

```js
function getSpaceIndices(str) {
  let spaceIndices = []
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === " ") {
      spaceIndices.push(i)
    }
  }
  return spaceIndices
}

let str = 'test string of whole words'
let strArray = str.split(" ").filter(s => s != " ");
let combinationArray = []

// let spaceRemoveCount = 1
/*
let spaceIndices = getSpaceIndices(str)
let currentIndex = 0
while (currentIndex < spaceIndices.length) {
  let tempStr = str.slice(0, spaceIndices[currentIndex]) + str.slice(spaceIndices[currentIndex] + 1);
  combinationArray.push(tempStr);
  currentIndex++
}
console.log(combinationArray);
*/

function print(str,current, start, merge){

  let s = ""
  if(merge){
   s =current+str[start];
  }
  else{
  s = current+" "+str[start]
  }
  start++;
  if(start >= str.length){
    console.log(s);
    return;
  }

  print(str,s,start,true);
  print(str,s,start,false);
  
  
}

print(strArray,"",0);
```

Comment: This gets the desired output. Although I still need to understand how its working but this is working correctly. Many thanks

Comment: This is similar to tree traversal problem, you can refer those and learn. For eg: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/